# Removing Firefox MATE screen from Ubuntu MATE

Tags: firefox, themes, mate, ubuntu-mate, 21.10

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 21.10.

I recently installed Ubuntu Mate and am very pleased with it. Firefox is my primary web browser. Ubuntu Mate starts up with a custom Firefox theme/package that displays the MATE welcome screen. I like it, but I prefer Firefox's default settings.

Ubuntu MATE was installed using the task package of `ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

Is there a way for me to install regular Firefox on Ubuntu MATE?

Here's what it looks like: *(this image was taken from an external website)*

[image: Screenshot of Firefox Ubuntu Mate]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my answer on **[Ubuntu MATE Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/).**

As **[Norbert_X](https://ubuntu-mate.community/u/Norbert_X)** (Popularly known as **[N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert)** on **[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)**) said in his **[reply](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-remove-the-mate-firefox-welcome-screen-from-firefox/24985/2?u=someone)** to my **[thread](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-remove-the-mate-firefox-welcome-screen-from-firefox/24985)**:

> You can override such behavior by removing two files using terminal commands:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -v /usr/lib/firefox/ubuntumate.cfg /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/all-ubuntumate.js
> ```
>
> and then restart Firefox.
>
>  Please note, that we do not pin/lock the `ubuntu-mate-default-settings` corresponding package version, so you should apply the above fix again when Ubuntu MATE 22.04 LTS will be released.

Now I'm getting the default screen back! (*Image taken from [an external site](https://user-media-prod-cdn.itsre-sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2021-08-11-16-35-39-7b5bb7.png)*)

[image: Firefox Ubuntu screen]